# Статический размер шрифтов

Tags: html

Как запретить обозревателю масштабировать шрифты? К примеру, у меня на сайте используется шрифт размера 12. В обозревателе выставлен 15 шрифт. Я не хочу чтоб шрифт был 15, а хочу чтоб не зависимо от настроек обозревателя оставался 12. Такое вообще возможно?

Answer (score 1):

Надо прописать все это в таблице стилей (css). Соответственно только там, где это необходимо - так вряд ли на сайте используются лишь шрифты одного размера.

1. Самый низкий приоритет имеют стили установленные в браузере по умолчанию, как например вертикальные поля у параграфов.
2. Более высокий приоритет получают обычные стили подключаемые пользователями.
3. Еще более высокий — авторские стили, то есть ваши.
4. Еще более высокий достается также авторским стилям, но у которых указан !important.
5. И наконец самый высокий приоритет получают стили пользователей с правилом !important. Это сделано для того, чтобы пользователи с ограниченными возможностями в любом случае могли изменить внешний вид страниц сайта под свои нужды.

Пример:
div {
   font: 12pt; !important
}
Припишет всем дивам 12 размер шрифта.
Переписать это может только пользовательский стиль.

Comment: На заметку - "небесно высокий приоритет" имеют стили прописаные в html странице с использованием модифиукатора `!important` (если предложенного варианта <b>culebre</b> не будет достаточно)